# I am using following code to send form data to email along with attachment but it only send attachment not data filled in form

Tags: php, email, attachment

I am using following code to send form data to email along with attachment but it only send attachment not data filled in form.

I also want to set the upload limit to 4mb

Any idea which could help me?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name1=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mob'];
    $applyfor= $_POST['applyfor'];
    $address= $_POST['Address'];
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $path =  $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
        $filename = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
        $file = $path;
        $file_size = $_FILES['resume']['size'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $name = basename($file);
        $header = "From: $name1<$email>"."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."--";
        $message = $name1."\n" .$email."\n" .$mobile."\n" .$applyfor."\n" .$address;
        $mailto = "uttamking@gmail.com";
        $subject = "New resume Receive";

        if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, '', $header)) {
            echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        } else {
            echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please consider use of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: And where do you set `$message`?

Comment: @giorgio i have updated the code..... if i use this code i am getting only text not attachment...

Comment: you're setting the variable _after_ you use it...

Comment: You can better use the link of @walkingRed, it's much easier, it' ll take care of complicated issues etc. etc. And if you don't want everyone to be sending mail to you, remove your e-mail address from the code ;)

Comment: Please check basic functionality to send email http://www.formget.com/send-an-email-on-form-submission-using-php/